# Facebook share button does not work in some situations

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I have a blog and I placed a facebook share button next to all my latest posts which appear on my landing page. (Title, Image, Short description, Facebook share button)

This share button looks like this:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.myblog.fr/article-path">Share</a>
```

On the article page I used this meta's:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ $title }}">
<meta property="og:type" content="actualite">        
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ $url }}">
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ $image }}">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="{{ $site }}">            
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ $description }}">
```

***The problem is:  It works on all desktops/tablets (with any facebook account) but on mobiles it works with just several facebook accounts and only the first time (if I want to share the same article again for the second time, it doesn't work).***

I will exemplify below:

For this examples I will use 2 facebook accounts and 2 websites.

1. Facebook account 1 ( our main facebook which can't share our posts on mobile multiple times)
2. Facebook account 2 ( which work perfectly on all devices )
3. Website 1 ( my website )
4. Website 2 ( a random website which offers the possibility to share posts)

<sup>This tests are made only on a mobile device</sup>

**Case 1: Facebook account 2 / Website 1**
[image]
Multiples shares allowed !

**Case 2: Facebook account 2 / Website 2**
[image]
Multiples shares allowed !

**Case 3: Facebook account 1 / Website 2**
[image]
Multiples shares allowed even if the second facebook popup looks a little different !

**Case 4: Facebook account 1 / Website 1**
[image]
Multiples shared **not allowed**. First share works fine but the rest of them don't. When I try to press post button I get redirected to this page in case I use an adroid or a white blank page in case I use my iphone (but the url is the same):
[image]

The complete fail url is :
    https://m.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/share/submit

Mention: On my blog (Website 1) I am asked to enter a security key each time I try to share something, I don't know if it has something to do with this or not. The thing is that from one facebook account I can share multiple times and from another just 1 time. I have to disconnect and connect again in order to share another time.

Another thing that I want to mention is that if this example I used the same post to share, but even if I pick other posts I will get the same problem.

Anyone knows what is the problem here? Thanks

Comment: _“I am asked to enter a security key”_ – what exactly does the message you are getting say?

Comment: On mobiles: Security Check: Please enter the text below {CODE} Submit / Try another . And on desktops I get lots of images and I have to click on the ones that I am asked.

Comment: So on Website 1 (my blog) I get this security check on both facebook accounts but I can share multiple times only with account 2.

Comment: That you get this message in the first place is probably a result of extensive testing on your part (so Facebook’s algorithms might think something shady was going on, if you posted the same content a multitude of times.)

Comment: I get the security message on both facebook accounts as I already said. And on one account I can share multiple times and on another one only for the first time, after that I get the error shown above.

Comment: And this is not the only account, I have more than 1 account which does not allow to share multiple times.

Comment: Test it with another URL, that does not raise this security check.

Comment: I already did: Website 2 = other url ; but again, with my personal facebook account I can share multiple times even on this url (Website 1) which has security check

Comment: Well then file a bug report, if you really think something is broken: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I don't know if something is broken or not. All I know is this fact which I posted here and I try to find a solution. It's obvious that I need to fix the security check also because it's annoying. I can't just switch the url because my application is at this url. And as a mention, I have 3 urls (dev, preprod, prod) where I get this problem.